# Curve Modifier distorting object I want to curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, distort

[image]I am trying to create a gothic tracery window, and I've been trying to work from this tutorial https://youtu.be/vXAYt2h_Tto (skipping over anything to do with unwrapping/texturing as I do not need that for this piece) and I cannot seem to get the curve modifier to work no matter what I do... Half the time it won't apply to my curve, and the other half the time, it distorts it and none of the 'fixes' or changes I make seem to solve the problem..

I have been looking on every help post, YouTube troubleshooting tutorial, and thing I can find for days, I've checked normals, rotations, origins,I've re-drawn this a bunch of times and I have only been able to get it working one time, which of course was for nothing as blender crashed immediately after I was able to get it to work- so obviously I am doing something quite wrong and I just cannot seem to figure out what. I have attached a few screenshots of the usual result. Not entirely new to the concept of 3D drawing but quite new to Blender, and I've been trying so many different 'fixes' that I have lost track of all that I've even tried at this point so any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

**Also should note: I figure this is possibly a large part of why I can't get it working, but I have been making my Arch (the curve I want to conform the trim to) by **importing an SVG as a grease pencil, and converting it to a Bézier curve** that I make a few adjustments (origin, rotation *before* converting to a curve, adjusting vertices after converting to a mesh, ect) and same with the Trim piece that I would like to conform to the curve. Does this have an effect the curve modifier?

Would be so grateful for any suggestions or insight! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of unnecessary steps. Why import as grease pencil instead of importing SVG directly? Why convert to mesh instead of keeping curve? Why not use a bevel object directly instead of deforming a mesh?

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 0):

To create a mesh of this type, you actually only need two curves:

- A curve, which should be the profile (cross section) of your mesh.
- A curve along which the profile should be applied.

So first select your arc. Then under *Object Data Properties* you will find the option to add a profile curve to create geometry with it.

Under *Bevel* you then simply add your profile curve.

**Note:** The profile curve must lie on the X/Y plane.

[image]

[image]